# why for loop not showing compile error when i check condition with "<+"?

Tags: java, loops

while practicing, I have accidentally written for loop as below

```
for (int i = 1; i <+ 100000; i++) {
        System.out.println("Iam lazy thread" + i);
    }
```

loop just worked ignoring the plus sign in the condition.

Comment: Curiosity demands I ask:  what did you think a putative `<+` was going to do?  Or did you actually mean to type `<=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java Language Specification includes an unary `+` operator (§15.15.3) which can be used to explicitly express the sign of a numerical value as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3).

So the expression

```
i <+ 100000
```

is parsed as

```
i < + 100000
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a compiler error because `+` symbol  just denotes the positivity of any number later to it.

As same in the math ,

`a = 5` and `a = +5` are same. You wrote the + which is not necessary as `100000` is already positive. You see the functional difference when you write `i < -100000;`

It is same as writing

```
int k = +10000;
```

or

```
int k = -10000
```

Answer (score 1):

"+" determines that 100000 is a positive number. You can try this one

```
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("i <+   :" + (i <+ 10000));
    System.out.println("i <-   :" + (i <- 10000));
```